# How to inject a specific entity into a service in Symfony 6

Tags: symfony

While performing an upgrade from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 6 I came across an interesting problem.

Let's say I have a Service that needs an specific Entity, see below:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;    

class MyAwesomeService  {

    private UserInterface $user;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $systemUser) {
        $this->systemUser = $systemUser;
    }
    
    public function execute() {
        // does something ...
        $this->mailToSystemUser();
    }

    private function mailToSystemUser() {
        // mail to the systemuser by using $this->systemUser;
    }
}
```

The intended usage of the Service is execute something and to mail the system user ( a specific User ).

I had the idea that it is possible to do this:

1. register one specific User entity ( the system user ) as a Service
2. manually wire the registerd User entity to a Service

My services.yml looks like this:

```
# services.yml

user_repository:
    public: true
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
    - App\Entity\User

system_user_admin:
    public: true
    class: App\Entity\User
    factory: ["@user_repository", find]
    arguments:
        - "1"

my_awesome_service:
    public: true
    class: App\Service\MyAwesomeService
    arguments:
        $systemUser: '@system_user_admin'
```

When I take a look at: `AppKernelDevDebugContainer.xml` I see this:

```
<service id="system_user_admin" class="App\Entity\User" public="true">
  <argument>1</argument>
  <factory service="user_repository" method="find"/>
</service>

<service id="my_awesome_service" class="App\Service\MyAwesomeService" public="true">
  <argument key="systemUser" type="service" id="webdsign.system_user_admin"/>
</service>
```

However, Symfony fails to inject the specific Entity, it gives me this error message:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Service\MyAwesomeService": argument "$systemUser" of method "__construct()" 
references interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" but no such service exists. 
You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "system_user_admin" service.
```

This is strange. So, how can I inject a specific entity to a Service in Symfony 6?

Comment: Entities of course are not services so no matter what you do it can be awkward.  You can look at how Symfony allows injecting the current user.  Your factory approach should work.  You probably just need to exclude MyAwesomeService from autowiring to make the error go away.  Slightly off-topic but S6 generally uses the service class names instead of aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing:

```
my_awesome_service:
    public: true
    class: App\Service\MyAwesomeService
    arguments:
        $systemUser: '@system_user_admin'
```

To:

```
App\Service\MyAwesomeService:
    public: true
    class: App\Service\MyAwesomeService
    arguments:
        $systemUser: '@system_user_admin'
```

However, I think it is better to inject the `UserRepository` to the Service. The System User can be retrieved through the Repository.

Comment: You could go one step further.  If all you really need is the system user's email (and perhaps a couple of other properties like name) then you could make a value object SystemUserEmail and create it using your factory service.  That would allow type hinting directly against SystemUserEmail whenever it is needed and get rid of things like 'system_user_admin'.

Comment: its ok its already using the repository as a factory. ` factory: ["@user_repository", find]`